How can I get a list of the tags used in Coin Market Caps Listings API e.g. ['mineable','memes','dapp','gaming',etc]
The listings API includes a JSON segment of tags associated with each coin or token. How can I get a complete list of all possible values of the tags for a coin or token?
I am using the following GET call: https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest
The JSON returned has a tags segment for coin data listed.
I tried to find an API call that might offer this, but not found it yet.
